# How to use for loop to fill background

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame

My goal is to fill my entire screen with small 50px/50px blocks representing a background in pygame.I wrote this program to fill left to right, have the pic move 50px down and fill left to right again. Instead, I get an infinite loop where it fills vertically only. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
def fill_background():
    tiles = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6] #these are background tiles

x = 0
y = 0

for int in range(0,25):
    rand = random.randint(0,5)
    gameDisplay.blit(tiles[rand], (x,y)) #blit tuble is equal to x,y coord of pic
    x = x + 50
    if width/x == 16: #no more horizontal pics needed
        y += 50 #add 50 y and reset 0 so it fills left-right top-bottom
        x = 0
    #if width/x == 16 && height/y == 10:
```

`

I believe this to be a scope issue with x maintaining x=0 even though I'm trying to increase it. If this is the case, how to I work around that?

Comment: Depending on python 2 or 3 and what width actually is you might use `width/x <= 1` instead.

Comment: Or just `x >= width`.

Comment: I recommend using the x,y to denote the tile number at that row and column, rather than its position in pixels. Then, when you are going to blit it, multiply it by the pixel size of tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the spacing in your question is wrong. I assume that width is meant to be the pixel width of the screen. In this case the condition for the row being complete is x>=width. I'm guessing that in your case, width = 50*16 which means that the first time round width/x always equals 16. This sets x back to zero which is what you observed.

Instead of the loop which runs 25 times (I assume you wanted 25 rows of tiles but instead you get 25 tiles), I think you want to keep going until y>height.

The correct code should be something like:

```
def fill_background():
  tiles = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6] #these are background tiles

  x = 0
  y = 0

  while y<height:
    rand = random.randint(0,5)
    gameDisplay.blit(tiles[rand], (x,y)) #blit tuple is equal to x,y coord of pic
    x = x + 50
    if x>= width: #no more horizontal pics needed
        y += 50 #add 50 y and reset 0 so it fills left-right top-bottom
        x = 0
```